# I want to concatenate the range of cells ad include commas

Tags: excel, vba

In one cell, I want to concatenate range of cells till the cell value become blank and also i should include commas. Please check the below code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lastRow As Long


Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Select
    lastRow = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).count
   Range("E2").Value = Range("E2:E" & lastRow & "", "").Value

End Sub
```

But this code is not working. Please help on this. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be using *Join Function*.
Something like:

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("E2").Value = Join(Application.Transpose(.Range("E2:E" & lrow)), ",")
End With
```

This will concatenate the value of *E2:Ex* and place it in *E2*. HTH.